# auditd が `32/64 bit syscall mismatch` の warning を出す

Tags: linux, ubuntu

今、手元の vagrant 環境(ubuntu14.04) で、 auditd をインストールしました。そして、次のコマンドをたたいたところ

```
sudo auditctl -a exit,always -S execve
```

次のメッセージが表示されました。

```
WARNING - 32/64 bit syscall mismatch, you should specify an arch
```

これは、どうして発生していて、どうやったら抑制できるのでしょうか。
これは、無視しても構わないのでしょうか。